# How to set the point of view in pcshow Matlab?

Tags: matlab, point-clouds

I was wondering if there is any way to set the point of view when visualizing point cloud in Matlab.

To show a point cloud I know you can do and use the mouse to move the 3D object:

```
pc = pointCloud(rand(100,3,'single'));
pcshow(pc);
```

But how do you set the point of view beforehand?

Answer (score 0):

changing POV can be done by view() function.
For example, view in X-Y plane.

```
pcshow(xyzpoints,c);
view(0,90); % X-Y plane
```

view in X-Z plane

```
pcshow(xyzpoints,c);
view(0,90); % X-Z plane
```